# iOS project builds for armv6 when armv7 is specified (target is iOS 5.1)

Tags: ios, architecture, build, compiler-errors, arm

I get a long list of errors that spit out (for every source file I have) linker errors to the `.o` files (stemming from said sources). The error for every one basically resolves to this:

`CompiledSource.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)`

Except that the issue is actually warning, technically. However, at the end of compilation/linking phase the project refuses to build with a simple `Linker command failed with exit code 1` error.

I've been spending the past 2 hours trying to figure this one out.

In `Targets->ProjectName->Architectures->Valid Architectures` I have both armv6 and armv7 selected. I ALSO have my build target set for iOS 5.1.

In my `Targets->ProjectName->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources`, I have all of my resources added (I assume this is where resources such as image and nib/xib files are added).

**Is there anything I can do about this?** I've tried cleaning the project, removing all files from `DataDerived` folder in XCode root, and even cleaning out `/var/folders`. Admittedly, this project hasn't been touched since at the very latest 2011.

I should note that I'm pretty new to iOS stuff (as well as Xcode). Unfortunately, this project is under an NDA as well so I can't reveal too much info. However, if anyone has any questions I will answer the best I can.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure its an iOS application? Because that sounds like its linked to a custom framework that got build for i386 (OSX-intel) which would probably never work on iOS.

Did you try to Product->Clean? or [alt] Product->Clean Build Folder ?

Maybe have a look at some example code from apple and see how these iOS projects are struktured.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion: I have tried both of those to no avail. AS far as the iOS projects examples, I'll look into them, but I'm hesitant to believe they may be of some help, considering the fact that this project hasn't been worked on in a year or two and most of the code has already been written. I've tried starting a new project and copying the source-code to that, but that just makes everything worse...

Comment: I'm no pro either. But usually these projects should work out of the box and not throw so many errors.

Comment: my architecture settings - maybe helps ---

architecture: Standard (armv7) ---
BaseSDK: Latest (my case ios6) ---
build architecture only: No ---
supported platforms: ios ---
valid architectures: armv7

Comment: another suggestion: write down the frameworks in the frameworks group-folder .. remove them (reference! not trash) .. goto targets->buildphases->link binary with libaries->remove all in there .. then (in the same link binary with libaries block) add the frameworks and make sure they are iOS 5.1 .. they should reappear on the left and you can (if you want) move them in the frameworks-group-folder again .. then clean and build

Comment: Thanks n0oitaf, I'll be sure to give that shot. I appreciate your suggestions.